# How to run a Docker to update a project

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using this project to run apps on heroku.
 https://github.com/kuwabarahiroshi/heroku-buildpack-nginx

Everything worked until now but now I need to update it.

I added this lines to scripts/build_nginx file

```
NGINX_VERSION=${NGINX_VERSION-1.14.0}

--with-stream_ssl_module \

--add-module=/opt/nginx_custom_build/ngx_brotli
```

So I updated the Nginx version and added some modules to config.

I suppose I need to run this in Docker now to build it before I can push it back to github and use it again.

How do I do that? I have Docker and I am using Windows. I tried a bunch of different thing but I just dont understand instruction or to say Docker.

This is what is written in README on the link below.

```
Customizable NGINX Config
You can provide your own NGINX config by creating a file named nginx.conf.erb in the config directory of your app. Start by copying the buildpack's default config file.

Customizable NGINX Compile Options
See scripts/build_nginx for the build steps. Configuring is as easy as changing the "./configure" options.

You can run the builds in a Docker container:

$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox cedar
$ eval "$(docker-machine env ceder)"
$ make build # It outputs the latest builds to bin/cedar-*
To test the builds:

$ make shell
$ cp bin/nginx-$STACK bin/nginx
$ FORCE=1 bin/start-nginx
```

I am simply lost. I have open command line and this projects is cloned on Desktop, Docker is running, I updated it by adding the lines that I need and I don't know what to do next?

Inside of project I see two dokcer files amongst others.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM heroku/heroku:16

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential \
  zlib1g-dev
```

and **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  heroku-16: &heroku
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/buildpack
    environment:
      STACK: heroku-16
    working_dir: /buildpack
    command: scripts/build_nginx /buildpack/bin/nginx-heroku-16

  cedar-14:
    <<: *heroku
    image: heroku/cedar:14
    environment:
      STACK: cedar-14
    command: scripts/build_nginx /buildpack/bin/nginx-cedar-14

  cedar-10:
    <<: *heroku
    image: heroku/cedar:10
    environment:
      STACK: cedar
    command: scripts/build_nginx /buildpack/bin/nginx-cedar

  shell:
    <<: *heroku
    environment:
      STACK: heroku-16
      PORT: 5000
    command: bash
```